# Running python on client side

Tags: javascript, python, turtle-graphics

I want to run python code on client-side in my web technology project. The objective is that there will be some input from the user, taken via JavaScript, is then fed to `.py` files which will produce some output to be displayed on the website at the same time.

Please suggest a suitable way like `brython` or `skulpt`. A brief explanation or quick links will be very generous.

I'll be using `turtle`, `numpy`, `manim`, `matplotlib` and such libraries is that is the concern.

Comment: You did not asked any question, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before posting. In any case [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) can be use for your request..

Comment: You might have to send the user's input to a backend server to be processed by the Python script.

Comment: @DavidDR I'm sorry, I was just asking about what to use. Can you tell me what brython or skulpt can do? I read that they are used for client side python.

Comment: @NikhilJagtap I don't any info about brython and skulp... as mentioned in my opinion its better to use python as server side. Flask is one of the best option you have on doing that...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to build and compile some application to run on the client machine, but modern web browsers do not have the ability to run python files. As mentioned in the comments, you'd have to get user input and then process it server side.